# Organize items of a list

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

How to organize a list items? Suppose, if i have a list l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
Requirement is to get a,b,c to one list, d,e,f to other and g,h,i to another list.Current implementation is

```
list l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
m= list()
for i in l:
    if (i.find("a")>=0) or (i.find("b")>=0) or (i.find("c")>=0):
        m.append(i)
        print m
```

and so as for next items.Is there any better logic to this? With current implementation Cyclomatic Complexity is high.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. you provided `list l = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]` with missing quotes, and you did not explain exactly what you want. Is the input list sorted? Shall the output list(s) sorted too? vague.

Comment: Sorry for the missing quotes!.Output list may not be sorted, I just want to group inputs in list l to different lists.

Comment: you can edit your question then.

Comment: `if i in ["a","b","c"]:...`? Could you please better describe the logic behind the selection?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you must not use `find` in the list because:

- you don't really need the index, so you just could use `if "a" in l`
- `find` or even `in` in a `list` has a linear (O(n)) complexity, so this is not optimal. Not noticeable on a small list, but with a million elements, it is.

with has linear complexity, and loop on the searched items instead of the list itself.

in a `set`, elements are hashed (and must be unique, then) ensuring a much better search performance (and insert performance too but that's not the point).

```
l= set(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
m=list()
for i in ['a','b','z','c']:  # I have introduced an extra element
    if i in l:
        m.append(i)

print(m)
```

result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

What is funny is the above code is that it works with a `set` but with a `list` because `in` is shared by all collection objects. Only the performance varies.
You could replace the first line by `l= ['a','b','c','d','e','f']` it would work but you'll get bad performance (well, not for 6 items, of course), just like your example in the question.

Proof for people still doubting about the power of the `set` object, here's a test to check if item is in the list. I have chosen the worst case for `list`, but can be done with another value.

```
import time

data=range(1000000)

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1,1000):
    999999 in data

print("list elapsed %f" % (time.time()-start_time))

data=set(data)

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1,1000):
    999999 in data

print("set elapsed %f" % (time.time()-start_time))
```

result:

```
list elapsed 17.284000
set elapsed 0.000000
```

not even close :) and you can reduce the searched value, the `list` value will decrease (but the `set` will always show 0)

Comment: what does set do here? Why can't l be list only?

Comment: The input has large number of elements.I just chose 6 for giving example. I can't do if "a" in l for each element! I know the complexity is high if we use find/or. I just want to have a solution to avoid these!

Comment: if you have a list as input, you have to create a set with the same elements to be able to use dichotomic search.